# How to install OpenCl and CUDA

Tags: 13.04, 14.04, nvidia, cuda, opencl

I have desktop computer :

- CPU : Intel® Core™ i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8
- GPU : GeForce GTX 770/PCIe/SSE2

I would like to  use OpenCL/ CUDA in my own C programs. I can use :

- old Ubuntu = 13.04/ 64 bit  ( because there is no CUDA Toolkit for latest LTS Ubuntu version), then installation should be "easy", but then will be no safety upgrades for Ubuntu
- latest LTS  Ubuntu = 14.04, but then I will have problems with installation.

Which options is better ?

TIA

Adam

Comment: Option 3: Use 12.04, since https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads lists a package for 12.04 as well.

Comment: @muru - 13.04 64bit as well - though [it is unsupported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_life) . the 12.04 deb will likely install in another Ubuntu versions, whether it is a good idea is debatable...

Comment: install `libcudart5.5` package